# RxJava2 migration

Tags: android, rx-java2

I need to execute one case as per below steps:

1. We hit a API call and get a video object from the API.
2. Update the pre existing video link.
3. Call API for refreshing URL.
4. Update the segment URL.
5. Emitting the segment from video to upload on backend server. I want all segment to be uploaded sequentially.
6. For each segment, I update the status in database.
7. Count the number of segment upload success.
8. If all segment are uploaded successfully, hit an API.
9. If successful, mark it as completed.

This is what I have written in RxJava2 but It is not working completely.

```
private void executeUseCases() {
    broadcastEvent(getvideoUploadInitialEvent());
    compositeDisposable.add(executePostvideoUseCase()
            .flatMap(new Function<video, Observable<? extends video>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends video> apply(video createdvideo) {
                LogDnaLogger.info("executePostvideoUseCase -> createdvideo : " + createdvideo.toString());
                videoUploaderRunnable.this.updatevideo(
                        createdvideo.getRemoteId(),
                        createdvideo.getvideoSegmentList());

                videoUploaderRunnable.this.broadcastEvent(videoUploaderRunnable.this.getvideoCreatedEvent());
                return Observable.just(mvideo);
            }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<video, Observable<? extends video>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends video> apply(video video) {
                return videoUploaderRunnable.this.executeRefreshS3UrlUseCase(video);
            }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<video, Observable<? extends video>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends video> apply(video refreshedvideo) {
                videoUploaderRunnable.this.updateSegmentUrls(refreshedvideo.getvideoSegmentList());
                videoUploaderRunnable.this.broadcastEvent(videoUploaderRunnable.this.getvideoUrlsRefreshedEvent());
                return Observable.just(mvideo);
            }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<video, Observable<? extends videoSegment>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends videoSegment> apply(video video) {
                return videoUploaderRunnable.this.emitvideoSegments();
            }
            })
            .concatMap(videoSegment -> {
        return executeUploadVideoUseCase(videoSegment);

    })
    .doOnNext(segment -> {
        Timber.e("Uploaded segmentPosition : " + segment.getPosition() +
                " --- Upload Duration : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - uploadStartTime) / 1000 + " Secs");
        videoUploaderRunnable.this.updateSegmentStatus(segment.getPosition(), VideoData.STATUS_UPLOADED);
        videoUploaderRunnable.this.broadcastEvent(videoUploaderRunnable.this.getvideoSegmentUploadEvent(segment.getPosition()));
        //return Observable.just(segment);
    })
    .toList()
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap(new Function<List<videoSegment>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(List<videoSegment> segments) throws Exception {
                videoUploaderEvent event = videoUploaderRunnable.this.getvideoUplodedEvent();
                Timber.e(" video comparision " + segments.size() + " actually " + mvideo.getvideoSegmentList().size());
                LogDnaLogger.info("Uploaded video : " + event.toString());
                videoUploaderRunnable.this.broadcastEvent(event);
                return Observable.just(segments);
            }
            })
            .flatMap(o -> executeMarkvideoCompletedUseCase())
    .subscribe(
            voidResponse -> {
        LogDnaLogger.info("video Upload Completed ");
        broadcastEvent(getvideoUploadSuccessEvent());
    },
    throwable -> {
        Timber.e("video Upload Failed with Exception : " + Log.getStackTraceString(throwable));
        videoUploaderEvent event = getvideoUploadFailureEvent();
        LogDnaLogger.info("Upload Failed video : " + event.toString());
        broadcastEvent(event);
    }
    ));
}

private Observable<video> executeMarkvideoCompletedUseCase() {
    mMarkvideoCompletedUseCase.setvideo(mvideo);
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        mMarkvideoCompletedUseCase.execute();
    }).andThen(Observable.just(mvideo));

}
```

The problem with this call is it is going into executeMarkvideoCompletedUseCase function but it is not hitting the API, I don't know why this API is not hit here.

Comment: Please put some more comments where you are facing problems.

Comment: executeMarkVideoCompletedUseCase() this function is not execution some how.

Comment: but this line executed?

`return Observable.just("Passed");`

Comment: I have edited the code and comment.